# We have lived and grown up together or

Tags: sentence-construction

Should I say

> "We have lived and grown up together"

or

> "We have lived and we have grown up together"

or

> "We have lived and grew up together"

?

Answer (score 1):

I think *grew up together* is already enough because growing up with someone implies living together. So, your first and second sentences while grammatically correct are a little bit awkward. The third example, I think, is wrong. I would rephrase the entire sentence like this:

> I've known him since we were kids. We grew up together.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, your first sentence "We have lived and grown up together" is the most correct because both "lived" and "grown up" are the past participles of their respective verbs. Just one "have" puts both verbs in the present perfect.

You should be aware that in this verb tense, the "living" and "growing up" are still happening (ie. you are still children or adolescents at the time of writing).